# Access XML Child Nodes Dynamically E4X ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, e4x

I want to create a utility function that requires accessing XML children nodes dynamically.

Sample XML:

```
var xml:XML = 
<root>
    <section>
        <lt target='foo'/>
        <lt target='foo1'/>
        <lt target='foo2'/>
    </section>
    <section1>
        <lt target='foo'/>
        <lt target='foo1'/>
        <lt target='foo2'/>
    </section1>
</root>;
```

I want to be able to access all the 'lt' nodes regardless of its parent node. Normally, you would do that like this:

```
var xList:XMLList = xml..lt;

//Output

xList = 
<lt target='foo'/>
<lt target='foo1'/>
<lt target='foo2'/>
<lt target='foo'/>
<lt target='foo1'/>
<lt target='foo2'/>
```

That works fine, however, I need to access the 'lt' node not knowing the name up front. For instance...

```
var nodeName:String = 'lt';
var xList:XMLList = xml..[nodeName]; //<-- Does not work.
```

I was hoping to get this done without using a for loop. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Victor

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out and would have put it as the answer, but I had to wait 8 hours. But in case anyone else is looking, the syntax is as follows:

    `var xList:XMLList = new XMLList(xml.descendants(node));`

Comment: Ah, you figured it the same thing pretty much. But I don't think you'll need to use `new XMLList` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need:

```
 var nodeName:String = "lt";
 var xList:XMLList = xml.descendants( nodeName );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're all the same depth into your xml, you can use `*` as a wildcard. For example:

```
var xml:XML = <root>
    <obj1>
        <test>a</test>
    </obj1>
    <obj2>
        <test>b</test>
    </obj2>
    <obj2>
        <lala>
            <test>c</test>
        </lala>
    </obj2>
</root>;
trace(xml.*.test);
```

Traces out:

```
<test>a</test>
<test>b</test>
```

`xml.children().test` would do the same thing, by the way.

Comment: This works as well... var list:XMLList = xml.*[node]; Thanks!

Comment: BTW how to get `<test>c</test>`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the E4X parenthetical operators, also called filters. And also use a wildcard operator to return all children. Very powerful, it will allow you to search by using a string.

```
trace("trace",xml..*.(localName() =='lt'));
```

Comment: Cool! var list:XMLList = xml..*.(localName() == node)